# Force abstract implementation to child of child

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I want something like this

```
    public abstract class abc
    {
        public abstract void test();
    }

    public class def : abc
    {
            // ignore test(), this is concrete class which can be initialized
            // test method is not needed for this class
    }

    public class ghi : def
    {
        public override void test()
        {
            // force test method implementation here
        }
    }
```

What are possible ways to do that. I want to ignore use of interface at GHI class as these are not under our application.

**Edit**

All of you are correct, but I need similar implementation. Point is I have various objects which has common functionality so I inherited from a class. I want to give this class to other ppl who must implement test method.

Comment: Unfortunately `[Obsolete]` carries through override chains, so it doesn't work (it would otherwise give a neat compile-time warning).

Comment: Aah, obsolete will tell user not to use it, I want user must use it. May be some pattern will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the Test method in your base class as Virtual and leave the method body blank. Therefore you can override it wherever you want to. This is more of a hack and using an interface is a better way to go.

```
public abstract class abc
{
    public virtual void test()
    {
    }
}

public class def : abc
{
        // ignore test(), this is concrete class which can be initialized
        // test method is not needed for this class
}

public class ghi : def
{
    public override void test()
    {
        // force test method implementation here
    }
}
```

**Or**

You can have another abstract class

```
public abstract class abc
{
}

public abstract class lmn : abc
{
 public abstract void Test();
}
public class def : abc
{
    // ignore test(), this is concrete class which can be initialized
    // test method is not needed for this class
}

public class ghi : lmn
{
 public override void test()
 {
    // force test method implementation here
 }
```

}
**NOTE** - This abstraction is completely dependent upon your domain. The suggestion is just a technical way to do it. Not sure if its aligned with the problem domain at hand.

Comment: Second option suits my requirement with slight change. Inherit lmn from def, to give straight line inheritence

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. `def` has to implement `test`, unless it is abstract too.

Answer (score 1):

**Edits in bold.**
Abstract means you MUST implement it in your child classes. **If you want to force the implementation of a functionality that not every "inheriters" have, you should be using interfaces. Here is what I would do :**

```
public abstract class abc
{
    // Everything you want here, but not "Test()".
}

public class def : abc
{
}

public class ghi : def, ITestable
{
    public void ITestable.Test()
    {
    }
}

public interface ITestable
{
    void Test();
}
```

Comment: I liked the idea but I want user to give compile time error than run time.

Comment: Then I would go with the last part of my answer; I think the architecture should be revised. For example, you could create an interface "ITestable" which only ghi would implement, and remove the abstract test from abc. That's just a suggestion.

Comment: I agree, but this makes user to do two implementation. Can we check in parent class if child has not inherited some interface so that during compilation it give error?

Comment: A base class should not know about who inherit the class, so I don't think there is a built in way to do this, and I wouldn't. What's wrong with forcing the user to implement some abstract members of the base class and some interfaces? I'll edit my answer to what I think you should be doing, based on the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible what you are doing. You can not add an abstract method to the base class (abc) which doesnt habve to be implemented in a class (def) which inherits from the base class or it has to be abstract too

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way. This is a definition problem, you say "i want every class which inherits from this class to have this method" and then try to create a child without it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make def class as abstract class.